# Is it possible to italicize journal names and book titles through the .bst file?

Tags: bibtex, formatting, natbib, italic

I am working on an article for a Springer journal, and the specifications for manuscripts clearly ask to italicize all journal names and book titles. Doing it manually feels stupid, so I wonder if there's a way to make the BibTeX style do the trick for me. I am currently using [`spbasic.bst`](http://code.google.com/p/setochapter/source/browse/spbasic.bst) (natbib compatible stuff), and I have no experience in the obscure `.bst` language. Any hints?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I took the liberty to format your post a little. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you say, the BibTeX stack language is a bit tricky. Here, we need to alter two functions. In a renamed copy of `spbasic.bst`, you first want to make journal names italic by altering `FUNCTION {article}`. It contains the lines

```
journal
remove.dots
```

which need so be altered to

```
journal
remove.dots
"\emph{" swap$ * "}" *
```

To alter book titles, changes are needed to `FUNCTION {format.btitle}`, which is short so I'll reproduce in full

```
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
  { 
    title "title" bibinfo.check
    duplicate$ empty$ 
      'skip$
      {
       "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * 
      }
     if$
}
```

In both cases, we are working with a stack containing 'the `thing` to be made italic'. First, I've added `\emph{` to the stack, then used `swap$` to put the `thing` after `\emph{` on the stack. The `*` concatenates the two, then I add `}` to the stack and concatenate again.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like magic! Could you please add the missing `"` after the first `}` in the first code bit to make it completely copy-pastable?

Comment: How would I use this to italicize the booktitles of conference proceedings? I bet the same line of code is usable, but I can't figure out where to paste it. :)

Comment: @anna-earwen I guess you want to modify `inproceedings` (the above change should alter `proceedings` entries). To do that, in the `FUNCTION {inproceedings}` change the `format.title "title" output.check` to `format.btitle "title" output.check`.

Comment: Would it make sense to modify the `FUNCTION {format.booktitle}` to look something like `booktitle "booktitle" bibinfo.check "\emph{" swap$ * "}" *`? It seems to work, I wonder if it covers all possible "booktitles" of the BibTeX entries. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @anna-earwen The style you've linked to was created using `custom-bib`. If you want to make more complex changes, I'd be tempted to rerun that system: manual changes may well go wrong.

Comment: And yet they distribute it with a Springer template, which makes me wonder :)

Answer (score 1):

To those who wonder and (possibly) struggle with Springer and their double standards (OK, I never said that): here's my take on BibTeX formatting, a manually modified [`spbasic.bst`](http://code.google.com/p/setochapter/source/browse/spbasic.bst): [`spbasicemph.bst`](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05905690188433134867). It brings the bibliography format as close to Springer [Swarm Intelligence journal](http://www.springer.com/computer/ai/journal/11721) standard as I could get.

Comment: File no longer available.