# Italicizing and Underlining journal and book titles respectively

Tags: bibtex, emphasis

I am trying to customize the bibtex environment using `spbasic.bst` file according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67724/is-it-possible-to-italicize-journal-names-and-book-titles-through-the-bst-file). I would like to italicize journal titles while underlining book titles.

Now if we provide command `\usepackage{ulem}`, then all the titles (journal and book) are underlined. If it is suppressed, then all titles are italicized. How can I separate the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure to do two things:

- Load the `ulem` package with the option `normalem`:

  ```
  \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
  ```

  This will allow the continued use of `\emph` to create *italic emphasis*. To create emphasis by underlining, use `\uline`.
- Change the style of emphasis used in [Joseph Wright's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67725/5001) to the question [Is it possible to italicize journal names and book titles through the .bst file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67724/5001)  Specifically, in your renamed copy of the file `spbasic.bst`, the function `format.btitle` should employ `\uline` instead of `\emph`:

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.btitle}
    { 
      title "title" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 
        'skip$
        {
         "\uline{" swap$ * "}" * 
        }
       if$
  }
  ```

Happy BibTeXing!